# Send a merge mail to a single recipient when a checkbox is checked with google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet which is open for editing from you.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qtUFXNZxvQL2Q4Pljw3NTk3Rr6EB5U5QPCJ_l9mQVY8/edit?usp=sharing
I would like it to send out a merge email to recipient in column O with a merge from column C -> M.

This should be done when a checkbox in column A is checked.

I have made a script with help from this page https://spreadsheet.dev/mail-merge-in-google-sheets which allows me to send to all recipients in column O.

But not only to the one in the row which is checked in column A.

```
/**
 * Returns a rectangular grid of values in a given sheet.
 * @param {string} sheetName The name of the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
 * @return {object[][]} A two-dimensional array of values in the sheet.
 */
function getData(sheetName) {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange().getValues();
  return data;
}

/**
 * Renders a template with values from an object.
 * @param {string} template The template to render.
 * @param{object} data The object containing data to render the template.
 * @return {string} The rendered template.
 */
function renderTemplate(template, data) {
  var output = template;
  var params = template.match(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g);
  params.forEach(function (param) {
    var propertyName = param.slice(2,-2); //Remove the {{ and the }}
    output = output.replace(param, data[propertyName] || "");
  });
  return output;
}

/**
 * Converts a grid of values into an array of objects.
 * @param {object[][]} rows An array of rows in the grid.
 * @return {object[]} An array of objects (each row became an object).
 */
function rowsToObjects(rows) {
  var headers = rows.shift();
  var data = [];
  rows.forEach(function (row) {
    var object  = {};
    row.forEach(function (value, index) {
      object[headers[index]] = value;
    });
    data.push(object);
  });
  return data;
}

/**
 * Sends an email for each row.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  var templateData = getData("Templates");
  var emailSubjectTemplate = templateData[1][0]; //Cell A2
  var emailBodyTemplate = templateData[4][0]; //Cell A5
  var emailData = getData("Data");
  emailData = rowsToObjects(emailData);
  emailData.forEach(function (rowObject) {
    var subject = renderTemplate(emailSubjectTemplate, rowObject);
    var body = renderTemplate(emailBodyTemplate, rowObject);
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowObject["Email"], subject, body);
  });
}
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, it is hard for me to understand exactly what you want. Can you confirm: Your script works correctly, only you want it to send a mail _only_ to the people who have a check in column A. So if they have a [✓] then send mail. Right?

Comment: Sorry for not clearifying this in my post. 
yes. The script works correctly but is sending out to all emails in column O.
I want it to send one email at a time. But only if check column A with a [✓] as you have written @iansedano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Add an `if` block in the `forEach` loop.

You need to modify the `sendEmails()` function:

```js
function sendEmails() {
  var templateData = getData("Templates");
  var emailSubjectTemplate = templateData[1][0]; //Cell A2
  var emailBodyTemplate = templateData[4][0]; //Cell A5
  var emailData = getData("Data");
  emailData = rowsToObjects(emailData);
  
  emailData.forEach(function (rowObject) {
    if (rowObject["Sendt mail bekræftelse"] == true) { // NEW LINE
      var subject = renderTemplate(emailSubjectTemplate, rowObject);
      var body = renderTemplate(emailBodyTemplate, rowObject);
      MailApp.sendEmail(rowObject["Email"], subject, body);
    } // NEW LINE
  });
}
```

#### Explanation:

The check boxes in your sheet are `true` or `false` when read by Apps Script. So within the `forEach` loop that sends each email based on each row (the `rowObject`), you can wrap all the actions in an `if` block to confirm if the check box contains a [✓], which is read as `true` , that is, `(rowObject["Sendt mail bekræftelse"] == true)`.

[image: true false checkbox]

Your `onEdit` trigger should also work now if it is bound to the `sendEmails` function. Every time a change is made in the sheet, it will check all the checkboxes and if there is a [✓], it will send.

#### Further reading:

In case its helpful, here are some references on the `if...else` syntax and `forEach`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Main concepts to grasp here are "conditional statements" and "for loops", in case you want to do some Googling.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that answers your question but you can set an `onEdit` trigger to run `.getRange("A2:A").getValues()` for each cells in the range. If equal to `TRUE` (the value for a checked box) and the next is empty, then for app-script to send an email?

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean @mkpersonal. I have set up a trigger that fires on edit, but it still sends out to all recipients in column O. How do I incorporate you suggestion? 
Still a noob grabbing code snippets instead of writing my own code...